# Etymologie des Feminisierungssuffixes "-in"

Tags: etymology, suffix

Was ist der Ursprung des Suffixes "-in" zur Feminisierung eines Nomens im Deutschen, und wie unterscheidet sich seine Geschichte im Vergleich zu anderen germanischen und indogermanisch europäischen Sprachen?

Zumindest Luther verwendete den Ausdruck 'Mannin' für 'Frau', das Suffix scheint also schon etwas älter zu sein. Viele germanische Sprachen, wie etwa das Englische oder das Norwegische, haben diese Suffix jedoch weitesgehend verloren.

Comment: dass Luther den ausdruck *"Mannin"* verwendet ist falsch und richtig zugleich. Die *"Mannin"* ist ausschließlich Eva, denn sie wurde als das weibliche gegenstück zum Mann geschaffen, deswegen drückt diese Form ihre Position besser aus als *"Frau"*. Im gegensatz dazu ist zum Beispiel Esra in der Bibel immer eine Frau gewesen.

Comment: [Ein Einstieg ins Thema](http://www.sprachlog.de/2014/08/07/vom-beck-und-der-baeckerin/)

Comment: @Vogel612 Der alttestamentarische Esra war mit Sicherheit ein Mann.

Comment: @Uwe autsch... stimmt. Ich vermute mal, dass ich Esther meinte. Die war jedenfalls eine Frau ;)

Comment: @Vogel612 Das klingt allerdings viel plausibler.

Comment: Interessant auch, dass Romanes das Suffix umdreht: Romni ist sie; Rom ist er. Plural Romnia und Roma.

Answer (score 3):

Offenbar ist der Ablaut [**"-in"**](http://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/-in) zur Bildung weiblicher Nomen schon sehr alt. Schon im Althochdeutschen finden wir zahlreiche so feminisierte Wörter:

> chuningin (Königin), hundynne (Hündin)

Damals kamen auch Endungen *-inna* und *-inne* vor.

*Franz Bopp* schreibt in seinem Werk *"Vergleichende Grammatik des Sanskrit, Zend, Griechischen, Lateinischen, Lithauischen, Gothischen und Deutschen"* (Dümmler 1833 S. 1187 f.):

> Im Althochdeutschen entspricht das Suffix *inna*, wahrscheinlich durch Assimilation aus *inja* für *inia*, so dass dem sanskritischen Feminincharakter ***ī***  sich noch der gewöhnliche Ausgang ***a*** (aus *â*, goth. *ó*) beigefügt hat. Beispiele sind: *gut-inna* Göttin, *kuning-inna* Königin, *meistar-inna* [...]. Im Nominativ und Akkusativ bestehen abgekürzte Formen auf *in*, wie *gutin*, *kuningin* (neben *gutinna, kuninginna*), worauf sich unsere neudeutschen Formen wie *Göttin, Königin* stützen.

Vermutlich stammt unser heutiges Ablaut *-in* als abgewandelter Form ursprünglich  aus dem Sanskrit. Leider schreibt auch Bopp nur wenig zu der unterschiedlichen Entwicklung in den anderen indogermanischen Sprachen.

Comment: Du meinst "stammt [...] ursprünglich aus dem Protoindoeuropäischen und ist mit der Femininendung  ī im Sanskrit verwandt", oder?

Comment: Nein nein, zu Bopps Zeiten war Urindogermanisch quasi gleichbedeutend mit Proto-Sanskrit. Dabei ist Sanskrit ein bespnders schlechtes Beispiel, nachdem dort alle kurzvokale auch im Auslaut zu *a* werden,

Answer (score -1):

Ich sehe da eine Parallele zu lateinisch una (eine), Femininform von unus einer und Zahlwort). Una/eine kann als Suffix leicht zu -in werden. Schon im Lateinischen haben wir das Feminin-Suffix -ina, zB gallus, gallina (Hahn, Henne).