# eisern, golden, hölzern - alter Genitiv?

Tags: genitive

Einige Nomen werden/wurden im Deutschen im Genitiv mit n flektiert.

> des Professoren, des Pianisten, des Cäsaren

Ist die n-Bildung für

> "stoffe(r)n" - aus diesem Stoff (auch: wie dieser Stoff)

auch ursprünglich ein solcher Genitiv?

Comment: Das klingt plausibel, weil es auch die alte Form `[Körper] von [Stoff]` gibt: „Ein Kelch von Gold“

Comment: "stoffern" habe ich noch nie gehort und ich wUrde sagen, das Wort gibt es nicht.

Comment: @rogermue... deshalb ist es auch in Anführungsstrichen, weil es ein Fantasiewort ist, dass stellvertretend für hölzern, blechern, steinern, gläsern, stählern steht.

Comment: Eine unklare Kennzeichnung von fikitiven Wörtern.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So verführerisch eine Etymologie aus einem alten Genitiv erscheint, es ist wahrscheinlich nicht so.

Betrachtet man die Etymologie einiger dieser Adjektive, so fällt eine Gemeinsamkeit auf:

```
Neuhochdeutsch  Mittelhochdeutsch  Althochdeutsch  Gotisch
-----------------------------------------------------------------
golden          guldin             guldin          gulþeins
eisern          iserin             isarnin         eisarneins
bleiern         bligin             bli(w)in        ?
ledern          liderin            lidirin         ?
hölzern         hülzin             holzin          ?
```

Die neuhochdeutschen Suffixe *"-en"* und *"-ern"* sind also aus einem älteren Suffix *"-in"* und möglicherweise aus dem noch älteren *"-eins"* entstanden, welches man wie auch [das feminisierende Suffix *"-in"*](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/8586/etymologie-des-feminisierungssuffixes-in) letztlich auf eine Wurzel im Sanskrit (*"-ina"*) zurückführte. <sup>E.G. Graff: Althochdeutscher Sprachschatz, Nikolai Berlin 1834</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Wenn man bedenkt, dass es Ausdrücke gibt wie "Von steinerner Eleganz" oder "mit metallischer Oberfläche", dann ist der Urpsrung im Genetiv nicht unwahrscheinlich.

Comment: Ich sehe nicht, wie das die Vermutung unterstützen soll ...